# Travelling A Grid Without Touching a Shaded Square

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

Each segment between two adjacent vertices has length 1 unit. How many ways are there to go from A to B along a sequence of 10 segments without touching a side or vertex of the shaded square?

[image]

I know that the answer is 72, but struggling to find how to arrive at that answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The number of ways to get to (0,k) or (k,0) is 1. The number of ways to get to (x,y) for x >= 1, y >= 1 is ways(x-1, y) + ways(x, y-1). Fill in the top row and left column, the proceed in rows filling in values according to this formula. Treat the vertices that touch the shaded square as having ways() of zero.

```
1   1   1   1   1   1
1   2   0   0   1   2
1   3   0   0   1   3
1   4   4   4   5   8
1   5   9  13  18  26
1   6  15  28  46  72
```

Comment: can you elaborate a little My version of code is getting ans 79 , I don't where am going wrong ..

Comment: @KnightKnight I have all 36 values in my answer. The 1s along the top row and left column, and the four zeroes, are set manually. Every other cell is the sum of its neighbor above and to the left. Compare your 36 to mine and find where we disagree.